# How to declare css "global" height? Inside the html file or inside the css file?

Tags: html, css

My code is working, but I'm a bit confused. Somewhere I read about that if you want your site to fill the whole page regardless of the viewport, then you have to declare the `height: 100%` inside the html file rather than inside the css because of older browsers. Is it true?

I don't have any problem with this solution other than it's looking ugly inside the html.

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
...
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 100%;" class="side-nav">
        <div class="nav-title">I am the title</div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100%;" class="content">asd</div>
    <div style="height: 100%;" class="side-bar">asd</div>
</div>
```

I didn't know how to ask Google about this question and I didn't find the answer where I read about this setup. Please if you think it's off-topic, let me know and I'll delete, but I'm really curious.

**UPDATE:**

Just to not misleading, I know how to declare it inside css, I was just curious about that is there any difference between the two solutions. :)

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.side-nav, .content, .side-bar {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
```

It works the same, now I know.

Comment: It's not a road block; you can use it any where u wish. For tracking purposes and for keeping stuff organized you can declare your own css an keep the `height` property there and use that css .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't right.

If you declare

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

in a `CSS` file,  it will be 100% regardless of view port.

And if you want EVERYTHING to be `100%`, just use this

```
*{
    height:100%;
}
```

in your `CSS` file.

`*` is a selector for everything.

Comment: Thank you! "If you declare in CSS, it will be 100% regardless of view port." That's my answer! :)